# oAuth authentication on every site visit

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, authorization, tumblr

I'm trying to implement a transient oAuth authentication for a web app I'm creating. Essentially, the user needs to login with the Service each time they visit my web app. Primarily it's to enable using the web app without me having to store any of the user's authentication data. I'm trying to use the Tumblr API.

My platform of choice is PHP. However I've never really worked with oAuth before and and am still learning. The following scenario illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

The scenario assumes that:

1. The user has already authorized my application in their Tumblr account.
2. Using my Tumblr Consumer Key, Tumblr Consumer Secret, I call to get request_token, which I later display to the user via a link.
3. Now on clicking the link above, I expect Tumblr to NOT to ask user to allow the app again (authorize in their account) and simply redirect user back and returning some info that will allow me to distinguish the user. There is no $_SESSION as user is trying login to the website using Tumblr

Is this even possible? If yes, can you help me figure out how to get this done?

Ps. I'm a complete oAuth Noob so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use Tumblr in a way similar to Facebook Connect, Tumblr does not offer this feature at the moment. ie: you can not use Tumblr to log into your site.

Tumblr's OAuth implementation will allow you to have the user allow access for your app to the users account indefinitely. Which means that your app will always be able to access the users account, whether they are logged into your site or not. They will still have to log into your site each time they want to access your app.

Here is a solid guide to OAuth. Tumblr uses OAuth 1.0 :
http://hueniverse.com/oauth/

Comment: Thanks. This is what I figured out as well which sucks. It would be great to have something similar to FB connect or "Twitter Sign In"